# Using Perl to find and fix errors in CSV files

Tags: perl

I am dealing with very large amounts of data. Every now and then there is a slip up. I want to identify each row with an error, under a condition of my choice. With that I want the row number along with the line number of each erroneous row. I will be running this script on a handful of files and I will want to output the report to one.

So here is my example data:

```
File_source,ID,Name,Number,Date,Last_name
1.csv,1,Jim,9876,2014-08-14,Johnson
1.csv,2,Jim,9876,2014-08-14,smith
1.csv,3,Jim,9876,2014-08-14,williams
1.csv,4,Jim,9876,not_a_date,jones
1.csv,5,Jim,9876,2014-08-14,dean
1.csv,6,Jim,9876,2014-08-14,Ruzyck
```

Desired output:

```
Row#5,4.csv,4,Jim,9876,not_a_date,jones (this is an erroneous row)
```

The condition I have chosen is print to output if anything in the date field is not a date.

As you can see, my desired output contains the line number where the error occurred, along with the data itself.

After I have my output that shows the lines within each file that are in error, I want to grab that line from the untouched original CSV file to redo (both modified and original files contain the same amount of rows).  After I have a file of these redone rows, I can omit and clean up where needed to prevent interruption of an import.

Folder structure will contain:

```
Modified:  4.txt
Original:  4.csv
```

I have something started here, written in Perl, which by the logic will at least return the rows I need.  However I believe my syntax is a little off and I do not know how to plug in the other subroutines.

Code:

```
$count = 1;

while (<>) {
   unless ($F[4] =~ /\d+[-]\d+[-]\d+/)
      print "Row#" . $count++ . "," . "$_";
}
```

The code above is supposed to give me my erroneous rows, but to be able to extract them from the originals is beyond me. The above code also contains some syntax errors.

Comment: You don't explain what the modified file contains. It is simple to find lines that contain errors, but fixing them automatically is pretty much impossible. The best you can expect is to delete the faulty data.

Comment: Please explain data you show as an example. It looks like a single file, but the first column says that each line comes from a different source. What's that about?

Comment: Sorry about that @borodin overlook that.  I meant to have the same file source, either way.  So in the script that you posted below, can you make an edit on it to show how to run the script on multiple files?

Comment: Then you should correct your question please. I have added to my answer to show how to handle multiple input files. I still don't understand what is supposed to be in `4.txt` etc.

Comment: Your last comment belongs beneath my answer. If you explain the problem then I am sure it can be fixed. Please don't abandon anyone's answer and write your own work-around. The author has spent a lot of time writing a solution that helps you, and it will be a frustration if you don't allow them to complete the task. Are you using a Windows system? If so then that is the problem.

Comment: I am most certainly using a windows system.  Your solution was very helpful, it also taught me the use of the variable ARGV and how it can be used @Borodin

Comment: I have amended my solution to work on Windows. Please see my comment beneath my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do as you ask.

*Please be certain that none of the fields in the data can ever contain a comma `,` otherwise you will need to use [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV) to process it instead of just a simple `split`.*

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', 'example.csv';

<$fh>; # Skip header

while (<$fh>) {
  my @fields = split /,/;
  if( $fields[4] !~ /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/ ) {
    print "Row#$.,$_";
  }
}
```

**output**

```
Row#5,4.csv,4,Jim,9876,not_a_date,jones
```

---

**Update**

If you want to process a number of files then you need this instead.

The `close ARGV` at the end of the loop is there so that the line counter `$.` is reset to 
1 at the start of each file. Without it it just continues from 1 upwards across all the files.

You would run this like

```
rob@Samurai-U:~$ perl findbad.pl *.csv
```

or you could list the files individually, separated by spaces.

For the test I have created files `1.csv` and `2.csv` which are identical to your example data except that the first field of each line is the name of the file containing the data.

You may not want the line in the output that announces each file name, in which case you should replace the entire first `if` block with just `next if $. == 1`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV = map { glob qq{"$_"} } @ARGV;  # For Windows

while (<>) {

  if ($. == 1) {
    print "\n\nFile: $ARGV\n\n";
    next;
  }

  my @fields = split /,/;
  unless ( $fields[4] =~ /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/ ) {
    printf "Row#%d,%s", $., $_;
  }

  close ARGV if eof ARGV;
}
```

**output**

```
File: 1.csv

Row#5,1.csv,4,Jim,9876,not_a_date,jones


File: 2.csv

Row#5,2.csv,4,Jim,9876,not_a_date,jones
```

Comment: @JDE876 If this solution answers your question, then please give it the check mark.

Comment: I edited my question to show that there was only 1 file source per file. The 4.txt is the modified file I am checking for bunk rows, the 4.csv is the original I was going to swap the bunk row with. Either way your solution was helpful, I ran it and got what I wanted. I even tested it a few times on smaller examples and it did just what I asked. However, I was having trouble doing it on the cmd with *.csv. The way I worked around that was ran the .pl against a group of files in a batch and appended the output. Example: perl findbad.pl file.csv > output.txt and >> for each other line.

Comment: The reason a parameter of `*.csv` isn't working for you is that the Windows command shell doesn't expand wildcards in its parameters. Adding the line `@ARGV = map glob, @ARGV` will do that for you. I have added it to my answer.

Comment: so glob allows you to call to certain file extensions when executing from the CMD.  Great trick!

Comment: `glob` is written to reproduce the behaviour of the Linux [`glob`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdln_glob.htm) command. It is a whole other language comparable to regular expressions, and you can say things like `glob '[135].csv'`

Comment: Actually, because `glob` splits on whitespace like the Linux command, that should be `@ARGV = map { glob qq{"$_"} } @ARGV`. Otherwise paths like `C:\Program Files` will be split into two parameters. I've changed my answer again to comply.